# How can I determine the connection method used by a MySQL client?

Tags: mysql, ipc

When using a MySQL client (e.g. `mysql`) how can I determine whether it connected to the server using a Unix socket file or by using TCP/IP?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Finding the transport

Try using `netstat -ln | grep 'mysql'` and you can see how it is connected by the output. if you have access to shell

On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file.

This occurs even if a `--port` or `-P` option is given to specify a port number.

If yould like to know the connection type from *within* the mysql CLI, use the '\s' (status) command.

```
mysql> \s
```

The output would have a line like one of the following (on Unix).

```
Connection:             127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
```

or

```
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
```

## Forcing a particular transport

To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use `--host` or `-h` to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for localhost, by using the `--protocol=TCP` option. For example:

```
shell> mysql --host=127.0.0.1
shell> mysql --protocol=TCP
```

The `--protocol={TCP|SOCKET|PIPE|MEMORY}` option explicitly specifies a protocol to use for connecting to the server. It is useful when the other connection parameters normally would cause a protocol to be used other than the one you want. For example, connections on Unix to localhost are made using a Unix socket file by default:

```
shell> mysql --host=localhost
```

To force a TCP/IP connection to be used instead, specify a `--protocol` option:

```
shell> mysql --host=localhost --protocol=TCP
```

### Protocol types:

- TCP: TCP/IP connection to local or remote server. Available on all platforms.
- SOCKET: Unix socket file connection to local server. Available on unix only.
- PIPE: Named-pipe connection to local or remote server. Available on windows only.
- MEMORY: Shared-memory connection to local server. Available on windows only.

A Unix socket file connection is faster than TCP/IP, but can be used only when connecting to a server on the same computer.

Comment: @Anil: thanks, you made it an excellent answer.